# How to prove that $\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(B)\subseteq\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A\cap X\setminus B)$?

Tags: general-topology

To prove the assertion I attempt two different way: but unfortunately both seem inconclusive. Below you can read the two different "demonstration".

1. $B\subseteq\mathscr{cl}(B)\Rightarrow X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(B)\subseteq X\setminus B\Rightarrow \mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(B)\subseteq\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap X\setminus B$ and now if $\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap X\setminus B\subseteq\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A\cap X\setminus B)$ the proof would be complete, but unfortunately I'm not able to demostrate this last passage.
2. $x\in\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(B)\Rightarrow x\in \mathscr{cl}(B)\wedge x\in X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(B)\Rightarrow x\in \mathscr{cl}(X\setminus A)\wedge x\notin\mathscr{cl}(B)\Rightarrow\{\forall V_x\in\mathcal{V}(x):V_x\cap X\setminus A\neq\varnothing\}\wedge\{\exists V_x\in\mathcal{V}(x):V_x\cap B=\varnothing\}\Rightarrow\{\nexists V_x\in\mathcal{V}(x):V_x\subseteq A\}\wedge\{\exists V_x\in\mathcal{V}:V_x\subseteq X\setminus B\}\Rightarrow\{\nexists V_x\in\mathcal{V}(x):V_x\subseteq A\}\wedge x\in X\setminus B$ and if from $\{\nexists V_x\in\mathcal{V}(x):V_x\subseteq A\}$ I could argue that $x\in X\setminus A$ the proof would be complete, but I fear that this is generally false.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: The value of the RHS in the title is ambiguous due to a shortage of brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $A,B\subseteq X$. We go to show
that $\overline{A^{c}}\cap(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq\overline{A^{c}\cap B^{c}}$.
Here $A^{c}=X\setminus A$ and $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure
of $A$.

To simplify notation, we denote $C=A^{c}$. Hence, we need to show
that $\overline{C}\cap(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq\overline{C\cap B^{c}}$.
Let $x\in\overline{C}\cap(\overline{B})^{c}$ be arbitrary. Since
$x\in\overline{C}$, there exists a net $(x_{\alpha})$ with $x_{\alpha}\in C$
such that $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$. Note that $(\overline{B})^{c}$
is an open neighborhood for $x$, so there exists $\alpha_{0}$ such
that $x_{\alpha}\in(\overline{B})^{c}$ whenever $\alpha\geq\alpha_{0}$.
Since $B\subseteq\overline{B}$, we have $(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq B^{c}$.
Therefore, for any $\alpha\geq\alpha_{0}$, we have $x_{\alpha}\in C\cap B^{c}$.
Hence $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha\geq\alpha_{0}}$ is a net in $C\cap B^{c}$
and $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$. It follows that $x\in\overline{C\cap B^{c}}$.

///////////////////////////////////////////////

We can also prove directly without using the notion of "net".
To prove: $\overline{C}\cap(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq\overline{C\cap B^{c}}$.

Let $x\in\overline{C}\cap(\overline{B})^{c}$. Let $U$ be an arbitrary
open neighborhood of $x$. Note that $(\overline{B})^{c}$ is open
and contains $x$, so $U\cap(\overline{B})^{c}$ is also an open neighborhood
of $x$. Since $x\in\overline{C}$, we have $C\cap\left( U\cap(\overline{B})^{c}\right)\neq\emptyset$. Observe that $(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq B^{c}$, so $\emptyset\neq C\cap U\cap(\overline{B})^{c}\subseteq C\cap U\cap B^{c}$.
This shows that $C\cap B^{c}$ intersects with every open neighborhood
of $x$ and hence $x\in\overline{C\cap B^{c}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct approach to

$$\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(B)) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}((X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus B))\tag{1}$$

could be: Pick $x$ in the left hand side of $(1)$. So $x \notin \operatorname{cl}(B)$ so there is some open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ that misses $B$. And if $O$ is open neighbourhood of $x$, so is $O \cap U_x$ and this set intersects $X \setminus A$ (because of $x \in \operatorname{cl}(X \setminus A)$) and is contained in $X \setminus B$ (as $U_x$ is), so $O \cap U_x$ (and hence $O$ too) intersects $(X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus B)$, and as $O$ was arbitrary, $x$ is in the right hand side of $(1)$. QED.

Tip: don't lose yourself in formalism and logical fanciness and just first reason about points and their relations to subsets, closures etc. It might give you an idea *why* the statement holds.